# How is the address line A20 enabled in modern hardware?

Tags: cpu, hardware, motherboard

In the olden times, the memory address line 20 (A20) of the 80286 and others was automatically masked by the IBM AT motherboard. It could be enabled using the keyboard controller. Then the 80486 changed to allow the toggle with the A20m pin.

Currently, there are [many](https://wiki.osdev.org/A20) methods to enable the A20, one of which uses port 0x64.

How are those implemented at the hardware level? Do modern motherboards still have hardware to toggle A20? Is the 0x64 port a special port for the CPU?

Comment: Does [Can the A20 line still be masked off on Haswell and successors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59919707/can-the-a20-line-still-be-masked-off-on-haswell-and-successors) help?

Comment: @ChesterGillon, very probably! I will take a better look at it. Thank you.

Comment: @ChesterGillon, could you answer, please, if I am correct here? If I understood correctly, an I/O message i sent to the PCH. The PCH can be configured to trap and ignore certain messages, like those to 0x64. Then, I guess PCH sends some signal somewhere somehow, which allows a circuit to mask A20.